# How to avoid string format when set logging level to high level

Tags: python

In my program, there are lots of logging and it seems there is overhead to format a string inside a debug log, even when I set log level to INFO.
Is there any way to avoid the overhead?

```
logger.debug("result is %s " % xxxxx);
```

Comment: `even when I set log level to INFO` why do you expected it to change when the level is different ? The level is just here to show it or now that's it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logger is actually equipped to deal with this:

> **logging.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)**
>
> Logs a message with level DEBUG on the root logger. The msg is the message format string, and the args are the arguments which are merged into msg using the string formatting operator. (Note that this means that you can use keywords in the format string, together with a single dictionary argument.)

This indicates that if you use a string format in `msg` that is compatible with the `format` method, the logger will apply the `format` method on `msg` and the rest of its arguments (both positional and named). `format` will not be called if the message does not need to be emitted (e.g., when you set the log level to "info")

In short, log messages should not be formatted (by explicit use of the `%` operator, the `format` method, or `f""` notation), but instead rely on the call to `format` the the logging method will perform.